# Replace multiline pattern in bash

Tags: bash, replace

*I'd like to replace this:*

```
          }
      ]
  }
  {
      "commits":[
```

*with:*

```
          },
```

*using any command available in `bash`*.

The text above is being parsed [from within the `bash` script itself](https://github.com/dreamyguy/git-log-to-json/blob/51534bbea0fda32f9bce44348d6c0e528c3a6daf/gitlog.json) (not from a file). The "input" is the contents of `git log` being parsed by 4 different piped commands, which chew and spit the output to a file. The piping looks like that:

```
git log (...) | paste (...) | tail (...) | awk (...) > output.file
```

My strategy so far has been to add an extra pipe and a command that replaces a `multi-line pattern` with a `single-line pattern`, something like:

```
git log (...) | paste (...) | tail (...) | awk (...) | 'replace-multiline' (...) > output.file
```

In other words, I haven't been able to find the right `replace-multiline` command yet. Maybe you can help me? ;)

#### What I have tried

I've used three days trying different spins on `awk`, `sed`, `grep` and even `perl` (the ones that claimed to solve the multiline search & replace challenge). None of them worked on my context. I'm not versed on any of these commands, so I've been prodding in the dark. *I'd really appreciate any pointers!*

> Background
>
> I'm working on a `bash` script that outputs `git log` to a valid `JSON` output ([project at github](https://github.com/dreamyguy/git-log-to-json)). It works just fine when the script is run from the root of the repository, but I would like to extend it so that it runs from the directory that contains all the repositories, hence outputting the `git log` for all repositories in `JSON` format in one single call.
>
> The script, which was moved to the parent directory and made to run on every subdirectory (which are `git` repos), return the output below (the script was also made to output the repository name as a property within each object item).

**The current output:**

```
  {
      "commits":[
          {
              "repository":"repo1",
              "commit_nr":"1",
              /* ... */
          },
          {
              "repository":"repo1",
              "commit_nr":"2",
              /* ... */
          },
          {
              "repository":"repo1",
              "commit_nr":"3",
              /* ... */
          }
      ]
  }
  {
      "commits":[
          {
              "repository":"repo2",
              "commit_nr":"1",
              /* ... */
          },
          {
              "repository":"repo2",
              "commit_nr":"2",
              /* ... */
          },
          {
              "repository":"repo2",
              "commit_nr":"3",
              /* ... */
          }
      ]
  }
  {
      "commits":[
          {
              "repository":"repo3",
              "commit_nr":"1",
              /* ... */
          },
          {
              "repository":"repo3",
              "commit_nr":"2",
              /* ... */
          },
          {
              "repository":"repo3",
              "commit_nr":"3",
              /* ... */
          }
      ]
  }
```

**The wanted output:**

```
  {
      "commits":[
          {
              "repository":"repo1",
              "commit_nr":"1",
              /* ... */
          },
          {
              "repository":"repo1",
              "commit_nr":"2",
              /* ... */
          },
          {
              "repository":"repo1",
              "commit_nr":"3",
              /* ... */
          },
          {
              "repository":"repo2",
              "commit_nr":"1",
              /* ... */
          },
          {
              "repository":"repo2",
              "commit_nr":"2",
              /* ... */
          },
          {
              "repository":"repo2",
              "commit_nr":"3",
              /* ... */
          },
          {
              "repository":"repo3",
              "commit_nr":"1",
              /* ... */
          },
          {
              "repository":"repo3",
              "commit_nr":"2",
              /* ... */
          },
          {
              "repository":"repo3",
              "commit_nr":"3",
              /* ... */
          }
      ]
  }
```

Comment: Perl is the [solution](http://blog.alestanis.com/2013/02/17/replacing-with-regexes-in-all-your-code-files/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use perl for this:

```
$echo "          {
              "repository":"repo2",
              "commit_nr":"3",
              /* ... */
          }
      ]
  }
  {
      "commits":[
          {
              "repository":"repo3",
              "commit_nr":"1",
              /* ... */
          }," | perl -pn -e "BEGIN{undef $/;} s/\}\s*\]\s*\}\s*\{\s*commits:\[/},/g"
```

yields

```
          {
              repository:repo2,
              commit_nr:3,
              /* ... */
          },
          {
              repository:repo3,
              commit_nr:1,
              /* ... */
          },
```

**Attention**: you might have to add `\"` around the `commit` word (this being an `echo`, the `"` disappear because they are not escaped by my copy-paste)

Comment: Your command didn't work when piped at the end of the command pipeline - but it was good because it helped me figure how my shell script was rendering the output. I tried receding one `regex` at a time, and couldn't get past the beginning of the rendering for each `git log`. That means the script runs once for every sub-folder that's a valid `git` repository and when it's done it renders the output. I decided to run `perl` after the first pipeline was done, getting the input from the "dirty" output and outputting the result to a new file. Worked like a charm!

Comment: This is how it turned out: `perl -pn -e 'BEGIN{undef $/;} s/\}\s*\]\s*\}\s*\{\s*"commits":\[/},/g' < gitlog_all.tmp > gitlog_all.json`

Comment: @WallaceSidhrée Great! I'm glad it worked out. Perl multiline regex is a very powerful tool :)

Comment: I just [updated my project](https://github.com/dreamyguy/git-log-to-json) and gave you the [credits for the edits](https://github.com/dreamyguy/git-log-to-json/commit/cab02528038b25fb6c840da5851e88bab0b14bc6#L0R70). That was all that was missing for the *Multiple Git Repositories Mode*. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like what you *want* is the flip flop operator in perl, but since what you *have* (from what I can glean from your current output) is a bunch of nicely formatted perl hashes, you could just create a new hash from combining the old hashes with any structure you like.  This perl script could then sit at the end of your pipeline and munge the data.

Comment: Thanks for the thoughts Adam. Yes, I tried quite a few variations, but the `regex` by itself wouldn't work. I don't know enough `perl` to figure what was missing, so I thought I would ask the question here and hopefully get some help... :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just use sed, the below worked on your sample input:

```
sed -En '1h;1!H;${;g;s/( +)}\n +\]\n + }\n +{\n + "commits":\[\n/\1};/g;p;}'
```

Comment: Hi Rob, really appreciate the time you put into this! I really wanted to upvote this answer, but I tested it and it didn't work. I spent a long time testing @alestanis `perl` solution first, which I eventually got to work, so I'll stick to that one... Cheers!